# Is the injection in a NoSQL database architecture also called SQL injection?

Tags: sql-injection, terminology, owasp-top-ten, nosql

Is the injection in a NoSQL database architecture also called SQL injection and is it still part of the [OWASP 2013 Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10), category A1 Injection?

For example, an injection in code that communicates with the following database architectures:

- Hadoop / HBase
- Cassandra
- Elasticsearch
- MongoDB
- CouchDB
- Berkeley DB

Comment: If you want a term to describe this kind of attack regardless of the underlying technology, use *code injection*; this covers injection into the PHP (or whatever) script as well.  (It looks like OWASP just calls it "injection", but I think the "code" qualifier is useful in making it obvious *what* is getting inserted where it shouldn't be.)

Comment: "SQL Injection" is a *type* of Injection.  Specifically, it is the type that tries to inject data into a SQL command stream.  If you are injecting data into a different type of command stream, then it is a different type of Injection, but it is *still* Injection.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Those are called [NoSQL Injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection) instead of SQL injections.

You can find more information about NoSQL injections, in the [OWASP Testing Guide](https://www.owasp.org/images/5/52/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v4.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

> Is the injection in a NoSQL database architecture also called SQL injection...

No, it is not called "SQL injection" but this is called a "NoSQL injection", you can read more about in an article titled ["Testing for NoSQL injection"](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection), written by OWASP.

> ... and is it still part of the OWASP 2013 Top 10, category A1 Injection?

Yes, this is a type of injection and that's why it is also categorized in OWASP category A1.